# ‘%s’ directive writing up to 49 bytes into a region of size between 16 and 163

Tags: mysql, c

```c
char fname[50];
char lname[50];
char company[50];
char hphone[50];
char wphone[50];
char hemail[50];
char wemail[50];
char haddress[50];
char waddress[50];
char birthday[50];
int choice=0;

printf("\n\n1.Add Contact\n");
printf("2.Edit COntact\n");
printf("3.Search Contact\n");
printf("4.Display Contact\n");
printf("5.Delete Contact\n");
printf("6.Exit\n");
printf("\n\n ENter your choice: ");
scanf("%d",&choice);

if(choice==1)
{
    printf("Enter first name:");
    scanf("%s",fname);
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s",lname);
    printf("Enter Company: ");
    scanf("%s",company);
    printf("Enter Home (phone): ");
    scanf("%s",hphone);
    printf("Enter Work (phone): ");
    scanf("%s",wphone);
    printf("Enter Email (Home): ");
    scanf("%s",hemail);
    printf("Enter Email (Work): ");
    scanf("%s",wemail);
    printf("Enter Address (Home): ");
    scanf("%s",haddress);
    printf("Enter Address (Work): ");
    scanf("%s",waddress);
    printf("Enter birthday: ");
    scanf("%s",birthday);
    char query[200];
    sprintf(query,"insert into contact values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",fname,lname,company,hphone,wphone,hemail,wemail,haddress,waddress,birthday);
    if(mysql_query(conn,query)==0)
    {
        puts("success");    
    }
    else
    {
            puts("error occured");
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when I try to compile this code:

```
‘%s’ directive writing up to 49 bytes into a region of size between 16 and 163 [-Wformat-overflow=]
   90 |             sprintf(query,"insert into contact values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",fname,lname,company,hphone,wphone,hemail,wemail,haddress,waddress,birthday);
```

Comment: `query` is only 200 characters, but the string can be over 500 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed query to 500 and now its working fine